# node on rqt_graph is in red color always

Tags: rosnode, raspberrypi, rqt-graph, network-setup, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

This question is for experienced ROS users. First about My setup which involves, a raspberrypi (B+ model, wheezy OS, ROS groovy deb installation) and desktop PC (AMD dual core, Ubuntu 12.04.5, ROS groovy). I use a simple wifi-router to setup connection between the two machines. I also have followed the network setup very carefully, which are as follows:

***Case 1: (Initial Setup)***

**machine A (Desktop-PC; ROS MASTER):** `ROS_HOSTNAME=desktop-PC; ROS_MASTER_URI=http://desktop-PC:11311;ROS_IP=192.168.xxx.5` (IP address of my PC)

**machine B (raspberrypi):** `ROS_HOSTNAME=desktop-PC; ROS_MASTER_URI=http://desktop-PC:11311;ROS_IP=192.168.xxx.10` (IP address of my raspberrypi)

now having said that, I start roscore on **machine A**, and with the above network setup I am able to view rosnodes on my raspberrypi with `$ rosnode list`. following which, I setup the `turtlesim_node` on **machine B**  after which I setup the `turtle_teletop node` on **machine A** . Now, when I issue command using the teletop node the turtle on **machine B** *does not move*. a quick check on rqt_graph, reveals that my turtlesim_node is in red color. (something is wrong!).

***Case 2:(Slight Change in the Network setup)***

**machine A (Desktop-PC; ROS MASTER):** `ROS_HOSTNAME=desktop-PC; ROS_MASTER_URI=http://desktop-PC:11311;ROS_IP=192.168.xxx.5` (IP address of my PC)

**machine B (raspberrypi):** `ROS_HOSTNAME=desktop-PC; ROS_MASTER_URI=http://desktop-PC:11311;ROS_IP=192.168.xxx.5` (IP address of my PC)

now the change is done only with ROS_IP. The remaining setup are similar to that in case 1 . Now, when I issue command using the teletop node on **machine A** to the turtle on **machine B** , *it moves!*.But, a quick refresh on rqt_graph, reveals that my turtlesim_node is still in red color. (I feel something is really wrong! or I am missing a point here!).

so, again I kindly request ROS users to clarify this issue.

Thanks,

Murali

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193345/node-on-rqt_graph-is-in-red-color-always/) by [MKI](https://answers.ros.org/users/8136/mki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 246 on 2014-09-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2014-09-23**:
Following the [this note](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_IP.2BAC8-ROS_HOSTNAME), note that `ROS_HOSTNAME` should take precedence over `ROS_IP`, and you really shouldn't need to set both. Try instead setting `ROS_HOSTNAME` on the RPi to the hostname of the RPi (not the desktop).

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2014-09-23**:
and for completeness, try not setting `ROS_IP` at all. Alternatively, use `ROS_IP` as you have it in Case 1, and don't set `ROS_HOSTNAME`. Also note, that for some network configurations, adding a `.local` to the end of `ROS_HOSTNAME` can help with name resolution.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-23**:
For a more detailed explanation, watch my ROSCon talk from 2013 to get a better idea of how all of these environment variables interact and impact topic negotiation: https://vimeo.com/67806888

**Comment by [MKI](https://answers.ros.org/users/8136/mki/) on 2014-09-24**:
Thank you, @jarvisschultz and @ahendrix ,  for the quick response. will try again with the above idea in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I watched the ROSCon talk by ahendrix, and tried out few different types of network configurations, I guess this might be helpful for anyone who is having trouble setting up their own network with ROS.

Things needed :

1. A router (DNS server), which is capable of assigning IP addresses.
2. connect all the devices which are part of your ROS ecosystem to this router. (also having access to the router homepage can be handy to get the mapping of 'devices to their respective IP address' ). if not try to use `$ ifconfig` command to find out IP address on each device.
3. On your **Master Device**, Just execute the following commands, Start with  `$ roscore`, now open another terminal, and issue the following commands,

   (For eg. Assuming the IP is 192.168.1.10, check yours and make suitable changes )

`$ export ROS_IP=192.168.1.10`

`$ export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.10:11311`

4. Now, On your **slave or Client device/s**, get the IP of your slave device/s and issue the following commands. Again, assuming your slave IP is 192.168.1.5 (check this and modify according to what you get)

   `$ export ROS_IP=192.168.1.5`

   `$ export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.10:11311`

**NOTE:** These commands are localized to the terminal you are currently working on. So, when you want to working on a new terminal make sure you issue these commands again. Also, It is not necessary to export your ROS_HOSTNAME. Be sure to export only your ROS_IP. This reduces all sort of complications.

5 . if you have done steps 1 to 4 correctly, then there should not be any trouble with your ROS network setup. Follow the same pattern in  all your successive  slave device/s.

Some of you might want to setup a direct connection between your PC and say for eg, an embedded device like Arduino or Rpi with an Ethernet cable. In that case make sure you follow the ROSCon video mentioned above, the last 5 or 7 minutes of the talk will give you an Idea as to what is essential for you in your setup.

Regards,

Murali

---

Originally posted by [MKI](https://answers.ros.org/users/8136/mki/) with karma: 246 on 2014-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1